# Is there a way to use geom_label_repel when a full dataset is passed to ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

Is there a way to use geom_label_repel when a full dataset is passed to ggplot?

I can use geom_label_repel() in the following example by including `mtcars` only within `geom_point()`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot() +
    geom_point(
        data = mtcars, 
        aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_label_repel(
        aes(x = 2.5, y = 23.92395),
        color = "red", label = "My car prediction"
    )
```

If I include `mtcars` within `ggplot()`, then geom_label_repel() gets "overwhelmed" with overlaps.

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
    geom_point( 
        aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_label_repel(
        aes(x = 2.5, y = 23.92395),
        color = "red", label = "My car prediction"
    )
```

Is there someway to pass data into `ggplot(data = mtcars)` and still use `geom_label_repel()`?

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
    geom_point( 
        aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_label_repel(
        data = NULL, # this doesn't work but is there something like it? 
        aes(x = 2.5, y = 23.92395),
        color = "red", label = "My car prediction"
    )
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59687794/2761575

Comment: What are you trying to do? "use geom_label_repel" to do what? It is typically used to label points, but it sounds like that is not what you want?

Comment: A more typical use would be something like `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = gear)) + geom_point() + geom_label_repel()` This labels each point in the data, moving the labels to avoid overlaps.

Comment: If you want a single label at a single point `geom_label_repel` is a poor choice. Use `+ annotate(geom = "label", x = 2.5, y = 23.92, color = 'red', label = 'My car prediction')`.

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/a/77446536/1100107>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out your data:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point( 
    aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_label_repel(
    aes(x = 2.5, y = 23.92395), data = \(x) filter(x, F),
    color = "red", label = "My car prediction"# , max.overlaps = 100 
  )
```

[image]

Comment: this is a great solution, but what is the logic of `data = \(x) filter(x, FALSE)`? I've never seen R code like this with a `\(x)`

Comment: @Joe it is the same as `function(x) filter(x, FALSE) `. As data object will be passed to function from parent (`ggplot()`) call it will use `mtcars` assigned to `x`. The result of the function is 0-row data.frame with the list of columns as in `mtcars`.